# "Multiplicative" Archimedean property in ordered fields

Tags: field-theory, order-theory, ordered-fields

There following are two equivalent formulations of the Archimedean property of an ordered field $F$:

1. *$\mathbb N$ is unbounded in $F$.*
2. (Formulation for the ordered group $(F, +)$)**.** *For any $x, \varepsilon > 0$ in $F$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $N\varepsilon > x$.*

Now, (2) easily implies (using that $(1 + y)^N \ge 1 + Ny$), the following "multiplicative" version:

3. (Formulation for the ordered group $(F^+, \cdot)$)**.** *For any $x, \varepsilon > 1$ in $F$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\varepsilon^N > x$.*

Now I wonder if this multiplicative Archimedean property (3) is *equivalent* to the usual one (1) (or (2)).

The beauty of the potential equivalence makes me believe that it might be the case.

But I will not be shocked to see a counterexample for this, because addition and multiplication in a field are not "the same". They differ on how they distribute, for instance.

Any thoughts?

Comment: With $\epsilon=2$, (3) implies (1) directly, no?

Comment: @Aphelli Oh yea! How did I not see that! I will accept your answer if you write that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer. Suppose (3) holds. Then, for all $x >1$, there is some $N \geq 1$ such that $2^N > x$ (taking $\epsilon=2$).

Thus $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded in $F$, ie (1) holds.